# Git: want to iterate through all commits on branch, and list files in each commit

Tags: git

I need to write a script that will

1. iterate through all of the commits on a branch, starting from the most recent
2. for each commit, iterate through all of the files in the commit
3. if it finds a file of type hbm.xml, store the commit to file and exit.

I have a script for step 2:

```
for i in `git show --pretty="format:" --name-only SHA1 | grep '.*\.hbm\.xml' `; do
    # call script here.....
    exit
done
```

Now, I need to figure out step 1.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Something like:

```
branch=master
for commit in $(git rev-list $branch)
do
    if git ls-tree --name-only -r $commit | grep -q '\.hbm\.xml$'; then
        echo $commit
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

Note that `git show` will only list files which have changed in that commit, if you want to know whether there is a path that matches a particular pattern in a commit you need to use something like `git ls-tree`.

Comment: Thanks, Charles. I actually do want only the commit where files were changed.

Comment: "$branch" should be quoted as a matter of course even though the hash should always be shell-safe.

Answer (score 15):

`git rev-list` will list all revisions reachable from a given commit in reverse chronological order, so you can pass it a branch name to get the list for that branch head backwards:

```
$ git rev-list master                                                                                    
a6060477b9dca7021bc34f373360f75064a0b728
7146d679312ab5425fe531390c6bb389cd9c8910
53e3d0c1e1239d0e846b3947c4a6da585960e02d
a91b80b91e9890f522fe8e83feda32b8c6eab7b6
...
```