# Calculate time between git commits

Tags: git, git-commit

I would like to calculate the time between commits in git, this (I hope) will give me a rough measure of my productivity. Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to measure productivity, it might be a nice idea to use the commit hooks to automatically update a database or a csv file somewhere that contains time data which you can later graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can send the output of `git log` to a file, then you're halfway there already. I'm not sure what language you're most comfortable with, but I know it's easy to do in a bash script.

Comment: Add a `--format=%ad` to the end to simplify the process greatly.

Answer (score 2):

This will print the date of the newer commit followed by the date of the older commit:

```
git log HEAD~[newer_commit] -n 1 --format=%ad; \
git log HEAD~[older_commit] -n 1 --format=%ad
```

You'll end up with date strings.  Use whatever language you like to calculate the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more complete example of using `bash` and `date` for doing this.

First, as noted in [Git: want to iterate through all commits on branch, and list files in each commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953767/git-want-to-iterate-through-all-commits-on-branch-and-list-files-in-each-commi) :

> git rev-list will list all revisions reachable from a given commit in reverse chronological order, so you can pass it a branch name to get the list for that branch head backwards

So, basically, the idea is that I use `rev-list` to iterate from HEAD backwards through the repo history, and at each revision, get the timestamp of current, and the timestamp of previous commit; get them as UNIX timestamps because then we can do integer arithmetic (difference) directly in `bash`; and finally use `date` to display the dates. So this `bash` script would be:

```bash
for ix in `git rev-list master`; do 
  thists=`git log $ix -n 1 --format=%ct`; 
  prevts=`git log $ix~1 -n 1 --format=%ct 2>/dev/null`; 
  if [ ! -z "$prevts" ] ; then 
    delta=$(( $thists - $prevts )); 
    echo `date -d @$thists +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` "-->"  \
         `date -d @$prevts +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` " ;= " \
         `date -d @$delta +'%H:%M:%S'`; 
  fi; 
done
```

Note that when you're at the first commit, there is no previous/parent commit, and so `git log` will fail with: `fatal: ambiguous argument '45e95c7...~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`; to avoid printing this message, I redirect the `stderr` to `/dev/null` in the `prevts` command, and then do the time delta calculation only if `prevts` is not empty. The output from this script is something like this:

```
2017-08-27 09:44:04 --> 2017-08-26 17:12:22  ;=  17:31:42
2017-08-26 17:12:22 --> 2017-08-26 16:48:24  ;=  01:23:58
2017-08-26 16:48:24 --> 2017-08-26 16:28:05  ;=  01:20:19
...
```

However, these deltas are one hour off - so for more correct display of the time delta, I used Python's `datetime.timedelta` -- so in the above script, you may want to replace the `` `date -d @$delta +'%H:%M:%S'`; `` line with:

```bash
         `python -c "import datetime as dt; d = dt.timedelta(seconds=$delta); print(d)"`
```

... in which case this log is generated:

```
2017-08-27 09:44:04 --> 2017-08-26 17:12:22  ;=  16:31:42
2017-08-26 17:12:22 --> 2017-08-26 16:48:24  ;=  0:23:58
2017-08-26 16:48:24 --> 2017-08-26 16:28:05  ;=  0:20:19
...
```

Comment: For me the deltas aren't one hour off but 19 hours off, meaning a 7-minute difference shows as 19:07:00 and a 9-hour difference shows as 04:00:00. Bitbucket's git shell doesn't have Python, so I just changed the delta line to subtract 19 hours in seconds:  `delta=$(( $thists - $prevts - 68400 ));` I also added a command to print *which* commit caused the elapsed time: `git log $ix -n 1 --pretty=medium`.