# Diff a list of commits against a single commit

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I have a list of commits starting at `REV1` and ending with `REV2`. I want to compare all changes between `REV1` and `REV2` against a single commit denoted with `REV3`.

How can this be accomplished using git?

Comment: This is probably relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953767/git-want-to-iterate-through-all-commits-on-branch-and-list-files-in-each-commi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this will help

```
for n in `git rev-list <parent of rev1>..rev2 <branch name>`; do git diff rev3 $n; done
```