# How to do cherry-pick only if no other commits update the files updated by the cherry-picked commit?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

For example, consider the following directory:

```
one
two
three
```

And the directory has the following commit history and branches:

```
dev                           master
 |                              |
commit1 --> other commits --> commit-wanted
```

`commit-wanted` updates files `two` and `three`.

After checking out `dev` branch, I want the cherry-pick of `commit-wanted` to succeed only if other commits between `commit1` and `commit-wanted` do not update `two` and `three` files.

Is it possible?

Comment: I can't make sense of your diagrams: there is no `commit3`, there is a `commit1` and `other commits` and `commit-wanted` but no `commit3`.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question. @torek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you do not need `git diff-tree`, `git rev-list` already have what you need.

```
git rev-list dev..master^ -- two three
```

After `--` you can specify files changed by target commits. So, this command returns all the commits between `dev` (excluded) and `master` (excluded) that modified `two` OR `three`.

Eventually, You can solve that by running a simple command from `dev`:

```
test -z $(git rev-list dev..master^ -- two three) && git cherry-pick master
```

Answer (score 4):

`git cherry-pick` does fail if there are merge conflicts (see example below), but if you want a more conservative check that fails even if the changes to the files can be merged you'll have to write one yourself.

Print a list of file names touched by a commit (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/424142/14516046):

```sh
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r "$COMMIT"
```

Print a list of commits in a range (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5953868/14516046):

```sh
git rev-list dev..master
```

Using these two commands you should be able to implement the check you want as a simple script. Writing the script is left as an exercise to the reader.

Example merge conflict:

```sh
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/tmp/.git/
$ printf '1\n2\n' > foo.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Add foo.txt'
[master (root-commit) f41e149] Add foo.txt
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 foo.txt
$ printf '1\n2\n3\n' > foo.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Append a line'
[master ce20740] Append a line
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ printf '1\n2\n3\n4\n' > foo.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Append another line'
[master 9738459] Append another line
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ git checkout -b dev HEAD^^
Switched to a new branch 'dev'
$ git cherry-pick master || printf 'git cherry-pick returned nonzero status\n'
Auto-merging foo.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in foo.txt
error: could not apply 9738459... Append another line
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
git cherry-pick returned nonzero status
$ git cherry-pick --abort
```